# change div color after scrolling 15% down with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, colors, scroll

I have this jquery code below which makes a div scroll. But I would also like it to change the div color to #32200F when is down 15% from the top.THen return to the original barckground when it is less than 15% from the top.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function() {
                var $scrollingDiv = $("#navbar");

                $(window).scroll(function(){            
                        $scrollingDiv
                                .stop()
                                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"}, "slow" );
                });
        });
</script>
```

Here is the CSS code of my original background.I can make it a class to make it easier:

```
#navbar {
     /* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
     background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
     background-color: rgba(50,32,15,0.5);     
     /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4c32200F, endColorstr=#4f32200F);
     /* For IE 8*/
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4c32200F, endColorstr=#4f32200F)";
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You should tell us what you've tried. Be more specific about the problem you're having. Currently your question reads like "please give me code for my requirement".

Comment: the colour has to change gradually or suddenly? 15% is related to the page height or to the viewport height? Please be more specific and show what have you tried so far.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan it is related to the page height...it can be 250px to make it easier.

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uMPuW/)

Comment: @A.V works great! the only issue is it goes back to white and my original background has some transparency. I apologize for not being more specific. I'll try to edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: just added the CSS code of the original background

Comment: @A.V never mind I did it. just removed white and left the quotes empty. great job! thanks

Comment: @mlatelcom : I'll post it as answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var $scrollingDiv = $("#navbar");

   $(window).scroll(function () {
       $scrollingDiv.stop()
           .animate({
           "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"
       }, "slow");
       $scrollingDiv.css("background-color", (($(window).scrollTop() / $(document).height()) > 0.15) ? "orange" : "");
     });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uMPuW/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
            var $scrollingDiv = $("#navbar");

            $(window).scroll(function(){            
                    $scrollingDiv
                            .stop()
                            .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0)+ "px"},"slow");
                           $(".yourdiv").css('background-color', 'blue');
            });
    });
```

Comment: this works good for changing color but it doesn't return to the original color when it scrolls back to top.

Comment: use it in `if` condition....